# How to add an Airflow Pool via environment variable?

Tags: airflow, connection-pooling

Just like it is possible to set connections via an environment variable following the name `AIRFLOW_CONN_{conn_id}`, is there a way to set pools?

This is so I can set up a local Docker test environment with all configurations populated.

Comment: Not sure if `pools` can be set via *environment variables*, but you can easily **create them programmatically** using [`create_pool(..)` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/common/experimental/pool.py#L45) of experimental api. For instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57765115/3679900) answer discusses creating `Connection`s programmatically in similar fashion