# apache airflow variables on startup

Tags: airflow

I'm learning Airflow and am planning to set some variables to use across different tasks. These are in my dags folder, saved as `configs.json`, like so:

```
{
  "vars": {
    "task1_args": {
      "something": "This is task 1"
    },
    "task2_args": {
      "something": "this is task 2"
    }
  }
}
```

I get that we can enter Admin-->Variables--> upload the file. But I have 2 questions:

1. What if I want to adjust some of the variables while airflow is running? I can adjust my code easily and it updates in realtime but it doesn't seem like this works for variables.
2. Is there a way to just auto-import this specific file on startup? I don't want to have to add it every time I'm testing my project.

I don't see this mentioned in the docs but it seems like a pretty trivial thing to want.

Comment: `"..I can adjust my code easily and it updates in realtime but it doesn't seem like this works for variables..."` It works for everything including `Variable`s, `Pool`s, & `Connection`s. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55896121/3679900) answer, it describes creating dynamic workflows and uses programmatic `Variable` updation to change structure of DAG on the fly (even as it is running)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [With code, how do you update an airflow variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54045048/3679900)

---

Here's an untested snippet that should help

```
from airflow.models import Variable

Variable.set(key="my_key", value="my_value")
```

- So basically you can write a *bootstrap* python script to do this setup for you.
- In our team, we use such scripts to setup all [`Connection`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53740885/3679900), and [`Pool`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136365/how-to-add-an-airflow-pool-via-environment-variable#comment102660313_58136365) too

---

In case you are wondering, here's the `set(..)` method from [source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8a7c37281c49751de5ea5ec14ccdb2dfe86e6d72/airflow/models/variable.py#L143)

```
@classmethod
@provide_session
def set(
    cls,
    key: str,
    value: Any,
    serialize_json: bool = False,
    session: Session = None
):
    """
    Sets a value for an Airflow Variable with a given Key
    :param key: Variable Key
    :param value: Value to set for the Variable
    :param serialize_json: Serialize the value to a JSON string
    :param session: SQL Alchemy Sessions
    """

    if serialize_json:
        stored_value = json.dumps(value, indent=2)
    else:
        stored_value = str(value)

    Variable.delete(key, session=session)
    session.add(Variable(key=key, val=stored_value))
    session.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I had in mind - by edit I meant actually opening that json file and manually editing a variable or two. I was wondering if there is a way to (1) have such edits appear in my airflow instance without manually reloading on the variable UI, and (2) automatically import the contents of that `.json` file when airflow starts up